# How to stay logged in as a user in webview on a site

Tags: android, authentication, webview

How can I mage a user stay logged in even if he exits the app and whenever he opens the app again and opens that site via webview he should stay logged in !

Comment: prolly via syncing cookies using `CookieSyncManager`

Comment: If your website already manages sessions, Webview will automatically use that.